# Jupyter notebook not automatically opening up in browser in pydroid

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pydroid

I am using pydroid from a long time. I could use jupyter notebook easily earlier but now when I installed it again to use there is a problem. It doesn't open up automatically in the browser. It just writes this screen. I don't know how to fix it. Help me please.

I tried few things but nothing works.
This is what it shows.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BAhq.jpg)

I have tried everything. I deleted, reinstalled it and installed jupyter notebook and everything but same problem. Nothing works.